# How do I subdivide a span10 into 12 columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I'm having trouble creating a fluid row within another column. My understanding is that I should be able to divide the span10 into 12 more columns but I'm not having any luck. The fourth span3 doesn't fit. Thanks for any help.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span2"></div>
      <div class="span10">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span3"></div>
          <div class="span3"></div>
          <div class="span3"></div>
          <div class="span3"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code fragment is correct, I use the exactly same construct. What I experienced is that if a spanX does not fit, then what I tried to put into it was too big for the available space. Try if it works out for example with:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span2"></div>
      <div class="span10">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span3"></div>
          <div class="span3"></div>
          <div class="span2"></div>
          <div class="span4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div
</div>
```

to get an idea if that's the problem.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

your have a class name "row fluid" on the 2nd div

```
<div class="row fluid">
```

which should be

```
<div class="row-fluid">
```

And the "span10" lacks the pair ">".

```
<div class="span10"
```

It should be

```
<div class="span10">
```

And by the way you need also one more

```
</div>
```

at the bottom to match with class="container-fluid".